# How do I add two xib files to my AppDelegate to support iPhone screen sizes?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xib, retina-display, appdelegate

I am having issues with the iPhone 5 screen size.  I have created **two xib files** (**MainWindow.xib** and **MainWindowiPhone5.xib**) so that my app is supported with both screen sizes.

I've been trying to code it on my AppDelegate.m, but it does not work.

Here's my AppDelegate code:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height == 1136){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainWindowiPhone5" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *tabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController];
    }
}

return YES;



self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];



// Override point for customization after application launch.
// Set the tab bar controller as the window's root view controller and display.
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

How do can I get both xib to work on my code?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions should be ::

For iPhone-4S or older Screen :

```
 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
 {
   ---- Your Code ----
 }
```

For iPhone-5 Screen :

```
 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
 {
   ---- Your Code ----
 }
```

Hopefully... It may be help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried implementing the code and I get the **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** error `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`. Should I change something for it to support the **xib** files?

Comment: Here's the code: `if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){ if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){ storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainWindowiPhone5" bundle: nil]; } else{ if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480){ storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainWindow" bundle: nil];` Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need to take 2 different storyboards. You can use only 1 storyboard, and keep all views autosizing.

Comment: My code will help you in case where you have static buttons or views those are not resizables, then you can adjust them by this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your initialization:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
     if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)){
             //move to your iphone5 storyboard
             [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *) bundle (NSBundle *)];
  }
     else{
             //move to your iphone4s storyboard
             [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *) bundle (NSBundle *)];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the suggested code, ran the app and it throws the following **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` Is there something I am doing wrong here? Thanks @Sun Tzu

Comment: Here's the code: `if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0){
                //move to your iphone5 storyboard
                storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainWindowiPhone5" bundle: nil];
            }
            else{
                //move to your iphone4s storyboard
                storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainWindow" bundle: nil];` **MainWindow** and **MainWindowiPhone5** are xib files. Thanks.